make matplotlib plot interactive with Dash
I found this thread shows how to create and visualise a directed  weighted graph.
I improved on the answer provided there, slightly:
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netgraph import MultiGraph

def create_graph_from_data(nodes, edges):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    
    # Add nodes from the provided list
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    
    # Add edges from the provided list of tuples (node1, node2, weight)
    for (node1, node2, weight) in edges:
        G.add_edge(node1, node2, weight=weight)
    
    return G

# Example usage:
nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # Custom list of nodes
edges = [
    (0, 1, 5),  # Edge from node 0 to node 1 with weight 5
    (1, 2, 3),  # Edge from node 1 to node 2 with weight 3
    (2, 3, 2),  # Edge from node 2 to node 3 with weight 2
    (3, 4, 4),  # Edge from node 3 to node 4 with weight 4
    (4, 0, 6),  # Edge from node 4 to node 0 with weight 6
    (0, 2, 7),  # Edge from node 0 to node 2 with weight 7
    (1, 4, 8)   # Edge from node 1 to node 4 with weight 8
]

# Create the graph from the custom nodes and edges
G = create_graph_from_data(nodes, edges)

# Display the graph
MultiGraph(
    G,
    node_labels=True,
    node_color="skyblue",
    edge_color="gray",
    edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight'),
    edge_label_fontdict=dict(fontsize=8),
    arrows=True,
)
plt.show()

Is there a way to make this interactive on Dash? I want to eventually be able to say: show me only nodes 0, 2 and 3.
